# UEFI Secure Boot keeps turning back on

Tags: boot, secure-boot

I'm running Mint 18 on an Acer laptop. I disabled UEFI Secure Boot when installing nvidia drivers, rebooted, typed in my password and selected disable secure boot.

However, as I'm tinkering and installing different nvidia drivers to try to get the display working right, it asks me each time to again disable secure boot.

Is this getting re-enabled somehow, or is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the model of your notebook. It looks like some BIOS/UEFI bug. Update the firmware to some recent version.